# Cant connect to CRM server via outlook 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have installed *CRM server* on my server and via browser on client machine ,

I have access to my CRM ,But when I'm trying to connect *my outlook to CRM* appear an

```
error as : There is a problem with communicate with Dynamics CRM server or server might be unavailable.
```

In other hand hand when I'm choosing *CRM ONLINE* the login page appear for me but show me error from user and password.

Anybody can help?
Thanks
Mohammad

Comment: Can you show more log and debug information ?

Comment: I have just the error page that says The server might be unavailable and erro with communication.

Comment: Did you check Event Viewer and trace [log](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/11/08/crm-2011-outlook-client-tracing/) ? Post it here.

Comment: @Mohammad Can you clarify if you are trying to connect to on-prem or online instance? If online, is it configured for Windows Live or ADFS authentication? Also what version of the Outlook addin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the [CRM 2013 Outlook Client (download here)](http://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/download/details.aspx?id=40344) ?

If no then follow the next [tutorial](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2013/09/15/installing-dynamics-crm-2013-for-outlook.aspx).

Comment: I have installed CRM for outlook also ,when Im trying to setup via configuration wizard  also I get error for communicaton or not available server.